# Facebook App additional permissions

Tags: ios, facebook, mobile, facebook-permissions

Inside Facebook, when still using sandbox mode for a mobile app, I am not able to get permissions (example: about_me and user_birthday) without applying for a submission to review knowing that I am working in sandbox mode!

How to avoid this! its really annoying!
Thanks

Comment: Users with a role in the app (admin/developer/tester) can be asked for any permission without prior review. And since those are the only ones able to use your app at all while it is still in sandbox mode … your question doesn’t make much sense. What is your problem here exactly …?

Comment: I am the admin and I have many other testers, we are not able to get more permissions without review

Comment: Then you’re likely doing something wrong. What exactly are you doing to request permissions from the user?

Comment: FBLoginBox requesting read permissions, that is it